# How to set Null-able Guid value in LINQ Query C#

Tags: linq, guid, .net-core-2.0

I have Guid which I mark null-able by

```
public struct abc
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? PreviousCalculatedId { get; set; }
    public Guid? NextCalculatedId { get; set; }
}
```

But I am getting build error on LINQ query for PreviousCalculatedId  and NextCalculatedId

error

```
   error is cannot implicitly convert type system.Guid to bool
```

.

```
 var answerDataView = (from Calc in dbContext.Calculation
                       where Calc .abcId == abcId && Calc .Id == GivenCalcId
                        select new abc
                          {
                            Id = mylist.listedItemId,
                            Text = Calc .Value,
                            NextCalculatedId? = sortedAnswerList.ItemOnRight[0],
                            PreviousCalculatedId? = sortedAnswerList.ItemOnLeft.ElementAt(0),


                               });
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also I think there is no need of nullable operator (?) while assigning values, simply omit it

Comment: error is cannot implicitly convert type system.Guid to bool

Comment: What are the datatypes for ItemOnRight and ItemOnleft?

Comment: they are List<Guid>

Comment: Have you removed the question mark and built the project again? I think the problem is due to question mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
var answerDataView = (from Calc in dbContext.Calculation
                      where Calc .abcId == abcId && Calc .Id == GivenCalcId
                      select new abc
                      {
                            Id = mylist.listedItemId,
                            Text = Calc .Value,
                            NextCalculatedId = sortedAnswerList.ItemOnRight[0] ?? null,
                            PreviousCalculatedId = sortedAnswerList.ItemOnLeft.ElementAt(0) ?? null,
                       });
```

And

Comment: I got error "operator ?? cannot be applied operands of type Guid or Null

Comment: does your sortedAnswerList contain elements? and are those nullable?

Comment: is possibility.. yes

Comment: you was right, I need to set values of Guid as                                        
        public Stack<Guid?> ItemOnLeft { get; set; }
        public List<Guid?> ItemOnRight { get; set; }